# Create json for jsonobject request in volley

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-volley

I have to create a json of structure :

```
{
 "user_id":"1",
"program_id":"2",
"test_id":["1","2","3","4"],
"answers":["a","c","d","b"]
}
```

I am unable to pass array of strings, when I pass the array of string it goes like:-

```
{
 "user_id":"1",
"program_id":"2",
"test_id":"[1,2,3,4]",
"answers":"[a,c,d,b]"
}
```

Can someone guide me how to create a json with required structure above?

Comment: Can you share the code you use for creating the first structure? Without it, I think I'm unable to help...

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: I myself want the code to create the first structure, I have the code to create the 2nd structure, will try the code given by @Santanu Sur later today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used following code to achieve it, `ansAr` and `qAr` are String arraylists:

```
JSONObject params = null;
        JSONArray jsonAns = new JSONArray(ansAr);
        JSONArray jsonQues = new JSONArray(qAr);
        try {
            params = new JSONObject();
            params.put("userId", mSessionManager.getToken());
            params.put("program_id", prgid); 
            params.put("test_id", jsonQues);
            params.put("answer", jsonAns);
            System.out.println("final params array" + params.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Obtained request json is as follows:

```
{
 "user_id":"1",
"program_id":"2",
"test_id":["1","2","3","4"],
"answers":["a","c","d","b"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this ..pattern for creating json Array of strings..

```
String[] test_id = {"1", "2", "3", "4"};
JSONArray json = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(data));
```